AnchorError thrown in program/src/state/candy_machine_data.rs:104. Error Code: ExceededLengthError
Getting the error below when creating the candy machine
  logs: [
    'Program CoREENxT6tW1HoK8ypY1SxRMZTcVPm7R94rH4PZNhX7d invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: CreateCollection',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program CoREENxT6tW1HoK8ypY1SxRMZTcVPm7R94rH4PZNhX7d consumed 6149 of 1000000 compute units',
    'Program CoREENxT6tW1HoK8ypY1SxRMZTcVPm7R94rH4PZNhX7d success',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program CMACYFENjoBMHzapRXyo1JZkVS6EtaDDzkjMrmQLvr4J invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: Initialize',
    'Program log: AnchorError thrown in program/src/state/candy_machine_data.rs:104. Error Code: ExceededLengthError. Error Number: 6013. Error Message: Value longer than expected maximum value.',
    'Program CMACYFENjoBMHzapRXyo1JZkVS6EtaDDzkjMrmQLvr4J consumed 16759 of 993701 compute units',
    'Program CMACYFENjoBMHzapRXyo1JZkVS6EtaDDzkjMrmQLvr4J failed: custom program error: 0x177d'
  ]


Based on error the provided uri or name is longer to maximum expected/permitted value.

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-candy-machine/blob/main/programs/candy-machine-core/program/src/errors.rs#L44
https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-candy-machine/blob/main/programs/candy-machine-core/program/src/state/candy_machine_data.rs#L107

-> https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata/blob/9676a219cccba6f6d7f6a5ec89f7c60d782bafb4/programs/token-metadata/program/src/state/metadata.rs#L13
MAX_NAME_LENGTH = 32
MAX_URI_LENGTH = 200


The error was cause by exceeding the name length value which is defined here https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-core-candy-machine/blob/ef83491a2e5d7d6ba9e8f0b1547753f2d1fcefff/programs/candy-machine-core/program/src/state/candy_machine_data.rs#L103C16-L103C31
As per the docs, the name prefix is constrainted by a maximum length of 32 characters.
This also applies to the URI which has a maximum of 200 character.
The constraints apply for both TM Candy Machine and Core Candy Machine
source: https://developers.metaplex.com/candy-machine/settings#config-line-settings
